# Visual Studio License : Compiling visual studio project with dotnet CLI

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, licensing

Is compiling with dotnet CLI a Visual Studio application  on a any machine requires licensing terms application ?

I have created a C# application with visual studio, I can build it on any other machine with only dotnet CLI . Should I be worried about the Visual Studio license in this case ? even for a big company ?

This application is like a tool used only by a few persons in a company and will never be sold to any.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should not be worried.

Microsoft make it very clear on their [.NET is FREE website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/free#:%7E:text=The%20programming%20languages%2C%20compilers%2C%20libraries,NET%20platform%20are%20all%20free.)

From their site: `"The programming languages, compilers, libraries, and runtimes that make up the .NET platform are all free. There are no licensing costs, including for commercial use."`